# Updating a Bitcoin wallet

Tags: wallet-recovery

I have a harddrive with an old wallet but I am not sure what I need to do to see how much BTC I have.

I have read quite a few notes, but I am looking for the latest information. I want to continue leaving my BTC in my private wallet until I decide to move it to an exchange or online.

How do I see how much BTC I have?

Comment: It might help to say exactly what wallet-related file(s) you have on the hard drive.

Answer (score 1):

To see how much BTC you have, you just need to open your wallet up, make sure it is fully synchronised, and then check your balance. If you don't want to wait for it to synchronise, you can copy and paste your addresses into a block explorer to see the balances on there.

Comment: are there any security concerns using these sites to check the amount of coin in my wallet? Does COPY/PASTING this info have any security implications?

Comment: @PeterJenkins addresses and public keys are designed to be made public, it's fine to enter those into websites, just never the *private* keys. BTW remember to accept my answer if it satisfies your question so it doesn't remain unanswered :)

Comment: Note that pasting your addresses into an explorer is a serious privacy leak in case someone is watching the server logs.